# Positioning, Margin, CSS

Tags: html, css, positioning, margin

I have two images that are enclosed by `<div>` but would like to create a selector id="image". But I would like to position the first image that takes out of the flow of the page where its left margin flush with the left margin of the parent element. On the second image, I would like its positioning right margin flush with the left margin of the parent element. Any suggestions?

```
Before:
 _
| |
|_| 

 _
| |
|_| 

Hello world



After:

 _                   _
| |   Hello world   | |
|_|                 |_|
```

I'm thinking that my CSS should look like:

```
#image-left img {
position: absolute;
margin-left: 0;
}
#image-right img {
position: absolute;
margin-right: 0;
}
```

My HTML is:

```
<div id="image-left"><img src="image/logo.jpg"></div>
<div id="image-right"><img src="image/logo.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this out, yet? Sites like http://jsfiddle.net/ are great for this kind of thing.

Comment: Does something go wrong with the code you've attempted?

Comment: I was playing around using http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_margin-left but no go. I'm curious how the pros do it.

Comment: @showdev I'm just using a notepad then refresh on Chrome browser. Nothing moves. The images doesn't move. I was trying to figure out how to position it without using "float" using this w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_margin-left. Nothing seems to move. I'll try this jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Check out [MDN's css guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FGetting_Started). Specifically on "boxes" and "layout". W3Schools leaves a bit to be desired...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to set the parent position property too:

```
#parent {
    position:relative;
}
```

and set the left and right property

```
#image-left img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
#image-right img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Note that whatever text you have in the middle will have to have some margin on left and right so it doesn't overlap with your floating images

Comment: @lbu I'll try that... yeah I did set up the parent enclosed with div tag with id="box" selector box {position: relative;} I think this should work.

Comment: Avoid position:absolute if you don't know exactly how to use it

Comment: @www.innovacall.com hello! I'm curious what's your reason for avoiding absolute position? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method using CSS `float` to position the images to the left and right of their parent container with some text between them:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="image-left">
        <img src="image/logo.jpg" />
    </div>
    Hello World
    <div id="image-right">
        <img src="image/logo.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
div#container {
    width:50%;
    border:1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
}

#image-left {
    float:left;
}
#image-right {
    float:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JJEng/

### EDIT:

To simplify:

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="image-left" src="image/logo.jpg" />
    Hello World
    <img id="image-right" src="image/logo.jpg" />
</div>
```

```
div#container {
    width:50%;
    border:1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
}

img#image-left {
    float:left;
}
img#image-right {
    float:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JJEng/1/

Comment: thanks that works too. I'm on "positioning" chapter on this website rather than using "float". But this works too. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, okay. Understood.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-left"><img src="image/logo.jpg"></div>
    <div class="TextContent">Hello world</div>
    <div class="image-right"><img src="image/logo.jpg"></div>
</div>

.container div {
    float:left;
}

.container div img {
    display:box;
}

.container div.TextContent {
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u3JMz/

Comment: I like this approach. Thanks.

Comment: While I like www.innovacall.com's approach the one above is probably simpler to under for me :)